# c# Blazor Web Assembly Core Hosted - Automatic data refresh

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-server-side, background-process, blazor-webassembly

I on my PWA application which is always run in one big screen in conference room, I'm displaying records about today planned events, every record contains status and hour when start and end.
Every record have special status like: Finished, InProgress or next.

How find the best approach to determine when records should automatically refresh after end of actual InProgress.

Also, I would like achieve one constant refresh in next day, so that if someone will come to room at the beginning of day, will see meetings for actual day.

I know that I can set refresh every minute, but this not exactly what I want because i don't need this kind of frequently because meetings are from 8 to 16 and one day have just few of events.

Sample:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use signalR. where you can create a channel.
if a new record is insert then you can publish it to this channel. and subscribe to your PWA app.
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/signalr.

Comment: Yes, this is some kind of solution, but im not 100% sure if my data need this. Because I dont wanna focus on refreshing when someone insert new event because is rarity, calendars are filled many days in advance. I used SignalR to create real time chat and for that that was a perfect solution, for displaying sent/received message in real time. But for my case im not sure if this is what i want.
Far away, i implement Timer() which sending request for every 5 minutes and refresing data, but that's not ideal because half the request will be sent in vain when everyone is out of the office

Comment: another thought is you can add a refresh option like. every 30 seconds, 60 seconds, No Refresh. etc

Answer (score 0):

From your question and your comment above, I understand that there are 3 scenarios:

- Schedule an update: You can implement your own scheduler or use a third-party library: There are several options, here some from github (https://github.com/topics/scheduler?l=c%23)
- As @Imamul pointed, SignalR, to externally request a change
- Update the UI based on a Property change via `StateHasChanged()` for changes by `Finished`, `InProgress` status.

Would these work?